# How to pass the current clipboard value to "git commit -m" on Mac?

Tags: git, macos, clipboard

I'd like to pass the current value stored in the clipboard as the message of the `git commit -m` command. I tried the following:

```sh
# 1st way
pbpaste | xargs git commit -m
# 2nd way
git commit -m pbpaste
```

But neither command worked. How can I pass the current clipboard value to `git commit -m` on Mac?

Comment: `git commit -m "$(pbpaste)" `?

Comment: `pbpaste | xargs git commit -F-` See [`git help commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--Fltfilegt)

Comment: @phd but minus the `xargs`; see bk2204's answer.

Comment: @torek Oops, thanks! `pbpaste | git commit -F-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `xargs` here because it does some splitting that you won't want.  You could do `git commit -m "$(pbpaste)"`, which uses a command substitution (the `$()`) syntax.  That takes the standard output of a command, strips off any trailing newlines, and inserts it into that spot, which, with the double quotes, is sufficient to use that as the message.

However, on many systems, there's a maximum length for command line arguments, and it can be rather small.  A nicer way is `pbpaste | git commit -F-`, since the `-F-` reads from standard input and doesn't have the problem with command-line argument length.  That ensures that even if you wrote a minor novel for your commit message (which some Git contributors tend to do on occasion), then your command will succeed.